# PL/SQL function stops running after loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I feel like this code has been working all day but all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore and I can't seem to find the solution.

This Loop is inside a big function so I'll only post this:

```
FOR i in 0..t_strGroups.count
LOOP
  newStudentNumber := newStudentNumber || t_strGroups(i) || ' ';
  dbms_output.put_line(newStudentNumber); -- this outputs fine
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('test'); --this line doesn't output
```

When testing where the function stopped working I found that after this loop I can no longer output lines. Does anyone know what might have happened here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the loop is inside `begin` `end;` .. correct ? and you are returning the value ?

Comment: yup, the weird thing is that it worked all day, I'm trying to reverse the collection later in the code, but it does no longer reach that part of the function.

Comment: A PL/SQL block won't simply stop executing.  Perhaps an exception is being thrown somewhere inside the loop and swallowed by a poorly written exception handler that isn't shown here.  Perhaps you're just not seeing the last line because your GUI isn't grabbing the last line from the `dbms_output` buffer.  Perhaps your `dbms_output` buffer just isn't big enough.

Comment: Logically It seems correct , why dont you add an exception to catch the error ?

Comment: I don't think it is the dbms_output buffer, i've been outputting way more then I currently am. I'm quickly going to look into the exception handling

Comment: I guess that newStudentNumber exceeded its maximum size, resulting in an exception. Try outputting `t_strGroups.count` before the loop and `i` within the loop.

Comment: when I started writing the exception handler I thought of what the problem would be. i loop with a 0 based index. but `collection.count` returns a 1 based index, so I either should start looping from 1 or do `collection.count - 1`

Comment: Thank you all for the tips of catching exceptions by the way, I just started learning PL/SQL. so sorry for my ignorance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a bit more about this I found the answer.

In the loop I loop from 0 to t_strGroups.count. Because the first position of my collection is 0. but `collection.count` returns the ammount of values in the collection.

I have 5 values in my collection so `collection.count` returns 5. however, the last value in my collection has position 4. So when the loops gets to itteration 5 the code will crash. Since position 5 does not exist.

I guess it is just stupid of mine to overlook this. And I thought about removing this question. But I decided to post this answer. Maybe it can help someone some day!

**EDIT:**
According to the comment of Jeffrey Kemp the code doesn't crash it raises a NO_DATA_FOUND Exception. So it would also be smart to write an exception handler for that.

Comment: Accessing a non-existent element in a collection shouldn't "crash", it should just raise NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thanks for that addition. I'll catch that exception.